# HTML/JS: draw arbitrary lines between elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I apologize if this question is duplicated. Is it possible to draw straight lines between HTML elements using HTML/Javascript, and without using SVG/Canvas?  If yes, what would be the best method?

Comment: Can you not use <hr> tag?

Answer (score 1):

I've started using [LeaderLine](http://anseki.github.io/leader-line) combined with [PlainDraggable](http://anseki.github.io/plain-draggable).